# OS X Application AutoLayout Scroll view

Tags: objective-c, macos, autolayout

I am trying to make OS X application that has scroll view and 2 content views inside. I want to use auto layout to make user be able to make window smaller or bigger. If he makes it smaller scroll bars should appear and he needs to be able to scroll using them.

Content needs to be sticked to top of application window. If user makes window bigger then content then scroll bars need to disappear. Can someone help me how can i make this using constraints in interface builder.

I made something but when i make window bigger then content, content gets sticked to the bottom of window.

Here is image what i need to achieve.[image]

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? You said you've tried something, but you haven't given us any code.

Comment: i did everything from interface builder.

I Added one NSScrollView to view controller. Added Trailling, Leading, Top, Bottom space 0 to superview.

Then inside NSScrollView View component i added two Custom View's. 
View component of NSScrollView has top and leading set to 0 from Clip view and fixed width and height to some values.

View on left side has top and leading set to 0 and fixed height and width to some value.

View on right side has top set to 0, has horizontal spacing to left view set to 10 and fixed height and width to some value.

Uploading code now so you can test

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1wsufzp0i40y1e8/PromotionalFinanceOSX.zip?dl=0

Comment: Why don't you center the content programmatically?  What do  you find if you run a search for '[objective-c] nsscrollview center'?

Comment: Can you help me out with some example code how to set it programmatically? When i search "[objective-c] nsscrollview center" i get nothing.